# Nginx rewrite - swap path in URL

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Please help me with nginx:

url `www.server.com/products/customer/books` 
should be `www.server.com/customer/products/books`

So i need to swap `/products/` with `/customer/`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with a rewrite. Add the following to your server block:

```
rewrite ^/customer/products/(.*)$ /products/customer/$1 last;
```

Or, if you have multiple URLs (ie customer & business), you can do this:

```
rewrite ^/(customer|business)/products/(.*)$ /products/$1/$2 last;
```

Comment: Thanks for Your answer! But books isn't one category, there are a lot categories. I should use $ at the end?? So there are rearranged only customer and products, but after them goes something...

Comment: Awesome!!! Huge thanks! Last question - if in future i have something else than customer, for an example business? i should use this rewrite - `rewrite ^/(customer|business)/products/(.*)$ /products/(customer|business)/$1 last;` or `rewrite ^/(.*)/products/(.*)$ /products/$1/$2 last;` ???

Comment: The second one is correct. I added it to my answer as well.